# sliding letters animation in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I want to animate a `<h3>` to slide but i don't want it to be seen before the animation happens (the sliding of letters happens after the fade in of a div).
here is the code for the animation even though i don't think it helps

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div1").fadeIn(3000, function() {
        $("#div1 > h3").animate({ "left": "45.5%" }, 1500);
    });
    $("#div2").fadeIn(3000);
    $("#div3").fadeIn(1500);
});
```

here is the css code:

```
 #div1 > h3 {
     text-align: justify; /* or whatever you want to */
     position:absolute;
 }
 #div1 {
     display: none;
 }
 #div2 {
     display: none;
 }
 #div3 {
     display: none;
 }
```

if i make the h3 display: none; they wont appear.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$(document).ready()` fires several miliseconds after the CSS is applied. You need your element to be set in its correct position from the get go. Try setting your `#div1 > h3` in the CSS to something like `left: -300px` if it is sliding from the left side or something like `left: 120vh` if it slides from the right.